# Passing Dictionary to Analytics parameters: Urban Airship

Tags: ios, swift, parameter-passing, analytics, urbanairship.com

I am trying to implement Urban Airship Analytics in my app. I want to track each and every event in my app, for that I have made a different class and passed tracking data as a dictionary.

Following https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/ios/?swift#ios-screen-tracking link for the same.

I am passing parameters as:

```
    UAirship.shared().analytics.trackScreen("MainScreen")
    let event = UACustomEvent()
    event.properties = createParamDictionary(paramDict1,paramDict2)
    event.track()
```

As event *properties* is readonly, I can not assign/add data to it.
And the only option I can see is adding data one by one according to its defined type.
ie.

```
event.setStringProperty("abcd", forKey: "abcd")
event.setNumberProperty(123, forKey: "xyz")
```

Which is very tedious in my case.

So My questions are:

1. Am I doing it correctly?
2. If Yes, then is there any other variable or some way from which I can directly add parameters?
3. I also want to add User_id for tracking particular user. Any provision for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can create a custom method to **UACustomEvent** class which takes a dictionary and sets values using UA defined method, something like this,

```
extension UACustomEvent {

    func setEventProperties<T: Any>(_ values: [String: T]) {

        for keyValuePair in values {

            if let value = keyValuePair.value as? String {
                setStringProperty(value: value, forKey: keyValuePair.key)
            } else if let value = keyValuePair.value as? Int {
                setNumberProperty(value: value, forKey: keyValuePair.key)
            }

        }

    }

}
```

That way, you dont have to use *setNumberProperty* or *setStringProperty* each time, you want to set events. You can simply do it like this,

```
event.setEventProperties(["abcd": "abcd", "xyz": 123])
```

Comment: Hi @Sandeep. I have tried this but no luck. It is not updating the properties variable. :(